# Casting non primitive Double from JSONObject

Tags: java, json, casting, double

I have a database and a table in which there are two double columns:

- Longitude
- Latitude

The columns are allowed to be null because of some inner logic I'm using.
I receive the data from the database in JSON form.

**Where it occurred:**

I experience an issue when there's null in these columns.

The code that caused the error -

`Double longitude = myJSONObject.getDouble("Longitude");`

And the error it caused  -

`Value null at Longitude of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to double`

**What I tried:**

I used `Double` and not `double`, so I took a look into the java code and found out that `JSONObject.getDouble()` returns a primitive `double`, and there's no other suitable method that returns `Double`.

So I tried instead using `JSONObject.get()` which returns an `Object`, and then cast it to `Double` as so -

`Double Longitude = (Double)myJSONObject.get("Longitude ");`

But that raised the following error -

`Cannot cast 'org.json.JSONObject$1' to 'java.lang.Double'`.

And I found out `Object` cannot be cast to `Double`.

**Possible solution:**

The only way I see that can work is getting the value as a `String` and parsing it, but that seems inefficient. Is there any better way to receive a non primitive `Double` from the JSON Object?

As always, I appreciate any help provided.
(If something is unclear - please notify me and I'll do my best to be more coherent. I'm trying to improve in that field.)

**Edits: requested information**

**Generating the JSON: Android**

```
private class GetAllEvents extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try
        {
            URL myUrl = new URL("http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/GetAllEvents.php");
            HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection)myUrl.openConnection();
            request.setChunkedStreamingMode(0); //Probably default, just in case

            if (request.getResponseCode() != 200) //If request reached errors
                return null;

            InputStream stream = request.getInputStream();
            String jsonStr = convertStreamToString(stream);
            if (jsonStr.equals("[]")) //Empty array
                return null;
            return new JSONArray(jsonStr);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.w("myApp", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Generating the JSON: PHP (on distant server)**

```
<?require_once('MysqliDb.php');
$db = new MysqliDb();
//All closest events by date
$All = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Events;");
//Return in JSON
echo json_encode($All);
```

This generates a JSONArray, from which I extract the JSONObject in a for loop.

**JSON Result example:**
`[{"ModifiedOn":"2015-03-30 14:28:21", "Name":"בטיזאדו", "Description":"חברי", "Phone":"0500000000", "Type":0, "Address":"הסטודיו", "Password":"123456", "ID":1, "Latitude":null, "Organiser":"דפנה", "Longitude":null, "City":"Tzur yigal"}]`

(Please ignore the Hebrew)

And from here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < eventsArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject myJSONObject = myJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
    --- *Do other things* ---
    Double Longitude = (Double)myJSONObject.get("Longitude");
    Double Latitude = (Double)myJSONObject.get("Latitude");
}
```

I hope that's clearer.

Comment: Double longitude = myJSONObject.isNull("Longtitude") ? null : myJSONObject.getDouble("Longtitude");

Comment: Show us how you generated `myJSONObject` and the corresponding JSON.

Comment: @mkrakhin Can you please explain what do `?` and `:` do?
Maybe add this as an answer so I can mark it too.

Comment: @Neta http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: I still don't know what `myJSONObject` is. You've shown us a `JSONArray`.  Please give us a minimal, complete, and reproducible example. You don't have to involve DB calls and web services.

Comment: @Neta ternary conditional operator (if-then-else as statement). It's too short for good answer though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits go to @mkrakhin.
Worked like a charm.

```
Double longitude = myJSONObject.isNull("Longtitude") ? null : myJSONObject.getDouble("Longtitude");
```